# UIViewController moves when resizing objects on it

Tags: xcode

A quick one - I know that this has been asked a number of times but I can't find the answers on here. I have started a new project in Xcode and when I resize objects they resize from the other side of themselves, the controller moves with it etc. I know it is a simple setting somewhere but I can't find it - any helpers?

Comment: What do you mean the controller moves? Do you mean the top level view moves? Does it not take up the whole screen?

Comment: It is the point from which you resize does not actually move on the screen but everything else moves around it - it is a resizing setting somewhere.

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? The views may be trying to fit in their constraints when you resize one of the views.

Comment: Possibly - how would I know

Comment: Did you use Interface Builder to create the view layouts? It uses Auto Layout by default. Select the view controller in IB, and in the properties pane on the right, open the first tab, and see if the Auto Layout checkbox is checked.

Comment: Does it work when you disable the auto layout?

Comment: Yup - brilliant - head scratching has stopped

Comment: Awesome! I'll post the solution as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view controller is probably has auto layout enabled. When you resize one view, the others are resized according to their constraints.

To turn off auto layout: Select the view controller in IB, and in the properties pane on the right, open the first tab, and uncheck the Auto Layout checkbox.

[image]